# how to send post data to the server side using uploadify

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, uploadify

here is the my javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileUpload2").fileUpload({
        'method'   : 'GET',
        'uploader': 'js/uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'js/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': 'model/Properties/Manage Properties/add_files.php',       
        'folder': 'files',
        'multi': true,
        'buttonText': 'Browse',
        'checkScript': 'js/uploadify/check.php',
        'displayData': 'speed',
        'simUploadLimit': 22,
        'OnUploadEvent' : function(dom){
$(dom)('#fileUpload2').uploadifySettings(
    'scriptData', 
    {'ext':$('#osDeed').val(), 'ext2':'bab'}
    );
}

    });
});
```

this code only can send static data but not form data i dont know. i am just stuck please help.

Comment: can you upload files or not?

Comment: @nithi yes i can upload but problem is that i cant post the data to server side

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //uploadify function
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader': 'uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg': 'cancel.png',
        'folder': 'photos', //folder where images to be uploaded
        'auto': false, // use for auto upload
        'multi': true,
        'queueSizeLimit': 6,
        'buttonImg': 'images/upload.png',
        'width': '106',
        'height': '33',
        'wmode': 'transparent',
        'method': 'POST',
        'scriptData': {'myid':post_id}, //you can post the id here
        'onQueueFull': function(event, queueSizeLimit) {
            alert("Please don't put anymore files in me! You can upload " + queueSizeLimit + " files at once");
            return false;
        },
        'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $("#uploadfiles").append(response+",");
        },
        'onAllComplete': function(response, data) {
            showAll();
        }
    });
</script>
```

scriptData is used to send the post_id to the php file

uploadify.php

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $post_id = $_POST['myid'];
    include_once "config.php"; //connect to database

    //use this when uploading images into a folder
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';

    $fna = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $fna;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    //folder upload end

           $name2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
            $data2 = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']));
            $size2 = intval($_FILES['Filedata']['size']);



        $db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_files SET post_id='$post_id', filename='$name2', file_data='$data2'");

}
```

Comment: its passing null value

Comment: Are you getting id as null or you can't upload photos what's the problem?

Comment: i dont have any problem to upload any photos.. i just want to send the additional data at server side 'script': 'uploadify.php'

Comment: 'scriptData': {'myid':post_id}, using scriptData you can send additional datas. Before sending data, confirm the variable contains value or not. If the variable contains value, definitely you can get it in the server side

Comment: i can get the additional data if i use this 'scriptData': {'myid':'data'} but if i write the code like 'scriptData': {'myid':'<?php echo $_POST['fieldname'];?>'} then i cant

Comment: $_POST only contain value if the form is submitted. You can use jquery like this....id=$("#fieldname").val(); 'myid':id

Comment: yeah i tried this too $("#fieldname").val(); but nothing worked

Comment: fieldname has value or is it empty

Comment: It would be a simple mistake in your code. Please check it. You should get the id when you alert(id). If so, the code will work perfectly

Comment: thank you for your all replay..but really i am totally lost i have spended 2 days to find out the solution... would you please show me the tested code . thank you

Comment: I haven't tested this right now. It's my old code in a file. Please post your code here. I'll try to find out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you should change your method from 'GET' to 'POST', just like

```
method = 'post'
```

You can send any value via post to server side via formData property, and then update it "onUploadStart" event of uploadify
Your final code will look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fileUpload2").uploadify({
    'formData': {
          'ext': '',
          'ext2':''
    },
    'method'   : 'post',
    'uploader': 'js/uploadify/uploader.swf',
    'cancelImg': 'js/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'script': 'model/Properties/Manage Properties/add_files.php',
    'multi': true,
    'buttonText': 'Browse',
    'checkScript': 'js/uploadify/check.php',
     'onUploadStart': function (file) {
          $('#file_upload').uploadify('settings', 'formData', {'ext': $('#osDeed').val(), 'ext2':'bab'});
      },

     }

   });
});
```